# Alarm Manager is not activating broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am working on an application inwhich I am using `AlarmManager` for scheduling things. My Alarm is set. But this Alarm does not invoke `BroadcastReceiver` written to catch the event. I have searched a great deal but I have not found anything that solves the issue. I am posting my code, please have a look and see if I am missing something.

**AlarmManagerClass:**

```
public class ScheduleMessageManager {

Context context;
PendingIntent sender;
AlarmManager am;


public ScheduleMessageManager(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public void addAlram(int scheduledMessageID, long scheduledTime) {

    // Activate Broadcast Receiver to receive broadcasts
    activateBroadcastReceiver();
    //Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    // In reality, you would want to have a unique variable for the request
    // code
    intent.putExtra("scheduledMessageID", scheduledMessageID);
    sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, scheduledMessageID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Get the AlarmManager service
    am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, scheduledTime, sender);

    Log.e("In ScheduleMessageManage", "***** Alarm is set to the mmessage *****");
}

public void cancelPeriodicSchedule(PendingIntent sender) {
    if (am != null) {
        if (sender != null) {
            am.cancel(sender);
            sender.cancel();
        }
    }

    // Deactivate Broadcast Receiver to stop receiving broadcasts
    deactivateBroadcastreceiver();
}

private void activateBroadcastReceiver() {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    Toast.makeText(context, "activated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private void deactivateBroadcastreceiver() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    Toast.makeText(context, "cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

}

**My AlarmReceiver:**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

int pendingIntentID; // same as scheduledMessageID

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.e("In On Receive", "Alarm has Initiated Broadcast Receiver....");

    if (intent.hasExtra("scheduledMessageID")) {
        pendingIntentID = intent.getExtras().getInt("scheduledMessageID");
        Intent sendMessageServiceIntent = new Intent(context, SendMessageService.class);
        sendMessageServiceIntent.putExtra("pendingIntentID", pendingIntentID);
        context.startService(sendMessageServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

}

`OnReceieve()` is never called.

In My **Manifest.xml**

```
  <receiver
        android:name="myPackage.AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </receiver>
```

I am unable to figure out the does the problem lie. Please help me out of it. Thanks.!

Comment: have you checked for the time, is that correct ? are you using GregorianCalendar

Comment: Yes, I think time is correct as I also display it on my list where it shows right time.

Comment: It sounds daft, but have you checked that scheduledTime is in the future? (it's the absolute time to trigger the alarm, not the time to elapse before the alarm goes off). Sorry if you alreay know this and have checked.

Comment: it's about year issue with other calendars but if you have checked it it must be fine what about these other methods other then the addAlram

Comment: @NeilTownsend, Yes I have checked that user is not allowed to enter time from Past.

Comment: @AashishBhatnagar, these method are to activate and deActivate Broadcast receivers. I found this way on a tutorial i was following a few time back.

Comment: try not to use then in your code for once.

Comment: @AashishBhatnagar, I have used this way before in some other demo app and it was working. can you elaobrate on year factor you mentioned ?

Comment: Out of interest, did the answer below help or not? So I can improve my answers, it would be helpful to know, thanks

Answer (score 4):

A good tutorial on using Broadcast receivers is given in http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html. In essence, your receiver doesn't declare what events it will receive. The declaration in the Manifest file needs something like:

```
 <receiver
    android:name="myPackage.AlarmReceiver"
    android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="your.company.blah.mybroadcast" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And when you create the intent, it needs

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("your.company.blah.mybroadcast");
// All the other things you want to put in the intent
```

Comment: @Neil...it was an issue related with time. That was not getting updated at one place.

Comment: I faced the same problem so please @UsamaSarwar advise me what is the solution; is it related to timzone?

Answer (score 2):

I know that this has been answered already, but just for further reference as I ran into the same issue, make sure that your receiver tags are inside the    tags, but not inside any other tag such as activity (that's exactly the issue I had).

Also it helps a great deal to check that your alarm has been successfully registered, to so run:
adb shell dumpsys alarm

Answer (score -2):

You just need to registered your receiver with alarm manager this will call broadcast after every 60 second:

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, broadcastIntent, 0);

       AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        long timeInterval = 60 * 1000;

        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), timeInterval, pi);
```

In Manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name="myPackage.AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </receiver>
```