# Android: managing Alarm Manager

Tags: android, service, android-activity, alarmmanager

I'm trying to build an Android Application which integrate a reminder manager. I created a class in which I have a List containing all the reminders (these reminders are taken from a table in my local database). When the application is started for the first time, I would like that that the aforementioned class calls a method for getting reminders from database filling the List of reminders (temporally ordered). After this, I was thinking of calling an Alarm manager for setting the first reminder. When the alarm goes off I would that a Notification appears and a the next reminder is setted in the AlarmManager, and so on.

The question are:

1. what happens if my application is not running, and the alarm goes off?
2. can I execute a code in my application restoring the class that contains the List of reminders that is obviously destroyed?
3. Can anyone suggest me a different approach?

Comment: What do you do when alarm goes off. I have done something similar.

Comment: When the alarm goes off I need to show a reminder notification.

Comment: Notification in notification bar or some sort of pop-up/dialog?

Comment: I was thinking about dialog notification

Comment: Have you been able to trigger an alarm? If not please first do that. Then it would only be a matter of passing an intent. Do you know how implement an alarm.

Comment: Yes, I can implement and trigger an alarm. But I need a service that is never stopped. How can I be sure that the service is always running. E.g. if I kill the application in the task manager the alarm is stpped. Furthermore I need that when my device is turned off the alarm che go off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alarm is a service provided by the Android OS and not an Activity. So when your app is closed the alarms scheduled would not go wasted.

A simple example and link to a tutorial page is given at [Alarm Manager is not activating broadcast receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267483/alarm-manager-is-not-activating-broadcast-receiver/15267969#15267969). In essense you have a class in your application which extends BroadcastReceiver and overrides onRecieve method.

That method in that class will be called by the AlarmManager. It can then do a lot, even invoke an Activity which can remind user about alarm and in the background do the re-scheduling.

Comment: ie: In your application have a class which extends BroadcastReceiver and set the alarm to call this. In the onReceive method of that class catch the alarm and do what you will. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267483/alarm-manager-is-not-activating-broadcast-receiver/15267969#15267969

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That will appreciated if you could edit my answer and add that.

Comment: I've tried to merge my comment into your answer. It will only be visible when it's been reviewed.